# Child image in video tag downloads as well as the video

Tags: html, video, optimization, pagespeed

I'm just looking at the video tag on the [blog page](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/) announcing the new autoplay policy for mobile WebKit:

```
<video autoplay loop muted webkit-playsinline playsinline>
    <source src="/wp-content/uploads/forever.mp4">
    <source src="/wp-content/uploads/forever.webm">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/forever.gif">
</video>
```

I notice on desktop Chrome the gif downloads as well as the video. From my point of view that's not a good thing - I would like to download the gif only as a fallback if neither of the preceding two sources can be played. Is there any good way to achieve this? A `poster` attribute on the video tag wouldn't work either, as the image would always be downloaded.